# Access context fields in base template

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I have the following base template `base.template.html`

```
{{ a.b }}
```

and the following derived template `derived.template.html`

```
{% extends "base.template.html" %}
{% import "base.template.html" as base %}
```

I render `derived.template.html` as follows

```
return flask.render_template("derived.template.html", { "a": { "b":1 }})
```

and I get an error

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError

UndefinedError: 'a' is undefined
```

However, if base.template.html was as follows

```
{{ a }}
```

everything works.

Why does this happen? And How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the import line from your **derived.template.html** file.

```
{% import "base.template.html" as base %}
```